# NSMutableArray append NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to set the contents of my allArticlesArray, and then append the array with additional objects. Here is a snippet from my code to do so:

```
[self.allArticlesArray setArray:newsArray];
[self.allArticlesArray addObjectsFromArray:sportsArray];
```

newsArray and sportsArray are non-null (they each have five items), however, after this code runs, allArticlesArray is null. I am using ARC. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you forgot to initialize allArticleArray

```
self.allArticlesArray = [NSMutableArray array];

[self.allArticlesArray setArray:newsArray];
[self.allArticlesArray addObjectsFromArray:sportsArray];
```

or a bit concise:

```
self.allArticlesArray  = [newsArray mutableCopy];
[self.allArticlesArray addObjectsFromArray:sportsArray];
```

Comment: it is always causing confusion to new objective-c programmer, that sending a message to nil is not an error or raises an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
self.allArticlesArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:setArray];
[self.allArticlesArray addObjectsFromArray:sportsArray];
```